# How can I ask questions if I have a question ban or my account is suspended?

Tags: support, asking-questions, suspension, ban

I want to keep asking questions but I seem to have a question ban or my account is suspended.
I have more questions to ask!
How do I ask them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.
If you have a question ban or suspension, you can't ask questions.
This is not negotiable.

The bans and suspensions are there for a reason.
We hope the reason is clear enough from the feedback you have gotten.
If it isn't please ask for clarification once your suspension or ban is lifted.

**Do not try to circumvent the rules.**
If your account has been suspended, wait for the suspension to end.
New accounts created to bend the rules will be deleted.

You are welcome back after the suspension is over.
If you have difficulties asking questions well, please draft and redraft until you get a good one.
If a question gets closed, or downvoted, please edit it to improve it.
Improving old questions to get the reopened helps **remove the automatic question ban**.

Reflect on your own work and try to improve!
Many of my first drafts are horrible, but I keep rewriting until they are clear, interesting, and answerable.
Some questions I never finish writing because I realize that it can be easily fully answered by a quick online search.

Also make note of the feedback you have gotten previously.
Especially with a longer series of questions, we expect you to learn to use some basic resources yourself before posting a question.

Patience, please!